# Calculating kills and deaths in a game

Tags: performance, homework, basic-lang

I'm trying to make a program that calculates your k/d ratio (kill/death, which is used in FPS games to make people believe that it's skill), how many kills you need without dying once to reach a goalKD. It also has a part that calculates how many battles you need if you give the program your average battle kills and battle deaths.

Is there a efficient way to program it? Currently, the way I'm doing it is getting me into programmer-efficiency hell.

```
For i = 1 to 100000 {
    While GoalKD>KDratio {
      Kills = BattleKills + Kill
      Deaths = BattleDeaths + Death
      KDratio = Kills / Deaths
      i++
  }
}
```

I'm programming this in SmallBasic because I'm most familiar with it, and I think it's easily readable. Also, if possible, don't give the answer right away; give me some hints for me to practice my mind. Add the answer in a spoiler box.

Comment: There is nothing that changes in the `while` loop that affects its condition, so you would get stuck there.

Comment: Always prefer ++i over i++.  When you do i++, it sets a temp value to i, then adds one to i, then returns the temp for you to use.  With ++i, it increments i, then returns i.  Very very small efficiency gain, but still worth it.

Comment: As far as general hints, there a reason why there are a lot of math classes for CS majors. Some problem just get much less complex if you use math on them instead of trying to bruteforce a solution with general computing principles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the kills needed part, you are trying to solve this equation:

```
k{current} + n
--------------  = r
  d{current}
```

Where `r` is the target rate and `n` is the number you're looking for. Some basic algebra:

```
n = rd - k
```

For the battles part, you need to solve

```
k{current} + b * k{battle}            // current kills + additional kills
--------------------------  = r
d{current} + b * d{battle}            // current deaths + additional deaths

k{current} + b * k{battle} = r * (d{current} + b * d{battle})  // multiply both sides by d{current} + b * d{battle}

k{current} + b * k{battle} = r * d{current} + r * b * d{battle})  // just showing multiplication of r

b * (k{battle} - r * d{battle}) = r * d{current} - k{current}  // subtracting terms from each side

     r * d{current} - k{current}
b =  ---------------------------  // dividing by k{battle} - r * d{battle}
     k{battle} - r * d{battle}
```

In your code above, this becomes

```
need = Math.ceiling( GoalKD * Deaths - Kills )
battles = Math.ceiling( ( GoalKD * Deaths - Kills ) / (BattleKills - GoalKD * BattleDeaths) )
```

[I'm not a SmallBasic guy, so please forgive any syntax errors above.]

(Edited to fix math error re battles required and add comments to the math.)

Comment: The code works perfectly, however I don't understand the r that's multiplying dbattle at the 3rd line? Where did it come from?

Comment: I added some comments above. When you multiply both sides by `d{current} + b * d{battle}`, you end up with a term `r * b * d{battle}` on the right. Subtracting that from both sides moves it to the left. Pulling `b` out of both terms on the left gives you the `r * d{battle}` term on the next to last line.

Comment: SmallBasic, not SmallTalk ;)

Comment: @tomdemuyt, good point. I'm not a SmallBasic guy, either! :)

Comment: Uhm. Subtracting from both sides? What do you mean?

Comment: This is the "subtraction property of equality." If `a + b = c`, then you can subtract `b` from both sides, so `a + b - b = c - b`, which simplifies to `a = c - b`. That's what I did above (subtract `r * b * d{battle}` from both sides).

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the b that's multiplying kbattle, yet I did know that property. Oh well =]. Thanks for your help, it really amazed me how fast you replied with the efficient code!

Comment: Glad to help out! And they say algebra is useless in the real world... :)